# How to Convert a byte array to DSA private key?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, des

As a part of project implementation, i have done the following things: 
1. Generete DSA keys
2. Encrypt the private key using AES
3. Save into the file
4. Open the file and read the encrypted private key
5. I tried to convert the read value into primary key format but error comes here.
I am attaching the code of the above steps here :

```
public class Pgm {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
try {
            KeyPairGenerator dsa =  KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            dsa.initialize(1024, random);
            KeyPair keypair = dsa.generateKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keypair.getPrivate();
            byte[] key = "�u���1Ù�iw&a".getBytes();
            Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir"); 
            // encrypt the text
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            byte[] abc = privateKey.getEncoded();

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(abc);
            // System.out.println("len="+encrypted.length());
            File dir=new File(currentDir);
            File private_file=new File(dir,"privatekey.txt");
            if(!private_file.exists()){
                private_file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream fileos = new FileOutputStream(private_file); 
            ObjectOutputStream objectos = new ObjectOutputStream(fileos);
            objectos.writeObject(encrypted);
            objectos.close();
            fileos.close();

            File file_private = new File(dir,"privatekey.txt");
            FileInputStream fileo = new FileInputStream(file_private); 
            ObjectInputStream objos = new ObjectInputStream(fileo);
            Object obj = objos.readObject();
            byte[] encrypted1= (byte[] )obj;
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted1));
            if (decrypted.equals(new String(abc)))
               System.out.println("true");
            else
               System.out.println("false");
            Signature tosign = Signature.getInstance("DSA");
            byte[] val =  decrypted.getBytes();
            PrivateKey privatekey1 = (PrivateKey)val;
            tosign.initSign(privatekey1);   

      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

}

'
     `PrivateKey privatekey1 = (PrivateKey)val;`

shows the error as  inconvertible types

Comment: Not by trying to cast incompatible types. Have a look at the `KeyFactory` class.

Comment: Should i post the same question in cryptography or bitcoin communities in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you replace explicit casting with this:

```
PrivateKey privateKey1 = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(val));
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I got some error when i tried to execute the above line in my java code. java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big.at sun.security.provider.DSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(DSAKeyFactory.java:156) at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:372)
 at Pgm.main(Pgm.java:61)

Comment: If i generate private key using DSA and saved it in a file after encrypted it using AES, should i get back the private key from file by decryption ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't simple convert byte array to PrivateKey instance.
You can generate keys by [KeyFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html)

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. KeyFactory gives me new keys, right? But i want to get my old keys which is in encrypted form. So you are saying like there is no way to get back ma private key from byte[] ?